# Name for non-polynomial generalization of B-splines?

Tags: terminology, spline

(1-dimensional) Splines are functions defined over contiguous intervals delimited by knots. Between those knots, a spline is a low-degree polynomial function - but not the same function in every interval. Thus a spline can be characterized by its polynomial function coefficients in each segment.

Now, suppose instead of coefficients for a polynomial basis of functions, I choose some arbitrary functions. Again, their linear combination may differ between intervals.

What do I call such functions? That is, is there a commonly-used term for them? If not, would "generalized splines" do?

Answer (score 1):

People sometimes use splines whose basis functions are trigonometric or exponential functions. And these are still called splines.

[Here](http://www.jstor.org/stable/24901234?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) is a paper by Schoenberg on trigonometric splines.

See [here](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Exponential-spline-interpolation-Sp%C3%A4th/aa5a912f5c4f57e00ac9a2ab0d29c1d4cb0c76e1) for some early work on exponential "splines under tension".

In computer-aided design, it's very common to use splines whose basis functions are rational functions (quotients of polynomials). CAD folks call these things NURBS (Non-Uniform Rational B-Spline) curves and surfaces.